# Multiple Instances of the same type with same implementation in Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I've started using Hilt since it got stable. I'm also new to DI (Dependency Injection).

My question is if I have a single class, say `AdapterA`, and I want to provide a new instance every time its DI (using @Inject) requests it.

I've used the following code to provide the instance, let me know if I need to add/remove anything to make it work as expected.

```
// Kotlin

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class AdapterModule {
    
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun provideAdapterAInstace(): AdapterA {
        return AdapterA()
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I'm trying to inject the dependency multiple times in an activity then it always returns the same instance (like a `static` variable that stores once and reuses numerous times.

```
// Usage
class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Inject
    lateinit var instanceOne: AdapterA
    
    @Inject
    lateinit var instanceTwo: AdapterA

    ...
}
```

Help me understand what I did wrong or missed here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope annotations tell Dagger to only create one instance in the component with that scope.  In this case, that means `AdapterA` will only be created once per activity.  If you want to create a new instance of `AdapterA` every time, don't provide a scope.

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class AdapterModule {
    
    @Provides
    // unscoped
    fun provideAdapterAInstance(): AdapterA {
        return AdapterA()
    }
}
```